# AutoLayout not working in runtime iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have a view, for which I have set the constraints using `AutoLayout`. After setting the constraints, the preview looks like what I need to have as given below. [image: This is the preview]

Now when I run the project in the simulator. The `AutoLayout` constraints seem to be not there. The views are not inj the same position as in the preview. Note: I have not made any dynamic changes to the views positions in the code. I hope so. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to edit the question and add few more details like what constraints you are using and your current output when you are viewing in simulator.

Comment: see carefully for which size class you are applying constraints. if app is only for iphone turn off size class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting extra 64 px added to your top, this might be want you want:

```
 self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
 self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```